# SQL Server - Subtracting results of two SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I'm trying to results of two queries using Subquery in SQL Server.

What I'm trying to achieve is to Calculate number of customers that are part of "ProductX Promotion" and subtract the count of customers that are part of "ProductX Promotion" and have actually purchased ProductX within last 60 days. This gives me the count of enrolled customers who have not made ProductX purchase for better insights for marketing.

Initially I only had COUNT() hence it was easy to subtract the two. Now requirement is that the count broken down by State and Zip level of the customer. The problem arises here as I cannot use direct Subtraction, I tried NOT EXISTS but didn't work, I tried JOINs but still no luck. I know the solution is pretty simple but I cannot think of any.
Here's the original code with comments on what particular columns mean,

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT (c.CustomerNumber))
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN 
TransactionDetail t
ON 
c.CustomerNumber = t.CustomerNumber
WHERE c.ProductXPref = 1 --Indicates if Customer was part of ProductX promotion program.
AND t.TransactionDate > DATEADD(d, -60, getdate()))
-
(SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT c.CustomerNumber)
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN
TransactionDetail t
ON 
c.CustomerNumber = t.CustomerNumber
WHERE t.ProductXIndicator = 1 --Indicates if ProductX was purchased
AND t.TransactionDate > DATEADD(DD, -60, getdate()) 
AND c.ProductXPref = 1 --Indicates if Customer was part of ProductX promotion program.
) AS 'Column Name' INTO #TempTable1
```

Here's what I'm trying to implement,

```
SELECT 
(SELECT c.Zip, c.State, COUNT (DISTINCT (c.CustomerNumber))
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN 
TransactionDetail t
ON 
c.CustomerNumber = t.CustomerNumber
WHERE c.ProductXPref = 1
AND t.TransactionDate > DATEADD(d, -60, getdate())
GROUP BY c.Zip, c.State)
-
(SELECT c.Zip, c.State, COUNT (DISTINCT c.CustomerNumber)
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN
TransactionDetail t
ON 
c.CustomerNumber = t.CustomerNumber
WHERE t.ProductXIndicator = 1
AND t.TransactionDate > DATEADD(DD, -60, getdate()) 
AND c.ProductXPref = 1
GROUP BY c.Zip, c.State) AS 'Column Name' INTO #TempTable1
```

This is the error I see,

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 129
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Any pointers will help. Thanks.

Comment: can  only use into if there is from.. i suggest do an insert into

Answer (score 3):

I think you are making this much more complicated than it needs to be -- the first query can be written as

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c.CustomerNumber)
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN TransactionDetail t ON c.CustomerNumber = t.CustomerNumber
WHERE 
    c.ProductXPref = 1 --Indicates if Customer was part of ProductX promotion program.
AND t.TransactionDate > DATEADD(d, -60, getdate()))
AND  t.ProductXIndicator <> 1
```

As you can see if you just don't include these rows in the original count it is the same as doing another query and subtracting.

So the second is simply

```
SELECT c.Zip, c.State, COUNT(DISTINCT c.CustomerNumber)
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN TransactionDetail t ON c.CustomerNumber = t.CustomerNumber
WHERE 
    c.ProductXPref = 1 --Indicates if Customer was part of ProductX promotion program.
AND t.TransactionDate > DATEADD(d, -60, getdate()))
AND  t.ProductXIndicator <> 1
GROUP BY c.Zip, c.State
```

Comment: How multiple columns will be subtracted from one column?

Comment: I don't @user2407394 -- I just don't include the columns in the select -- no subtraction needed.

Comment: OP, this should work, if your queries are exactly what you have written... Accept this as answer if it works or mention actual queries..

Comment: this did work, I actually overlooked a query that I already have that does something similar except the other way. it calculates customers who have purchased the product but are not part of promotion. I just had to flip the conditions in WHERE clause.

Comment: @Sami.. Many times users don't post original queries (rather a sample query).. The way OP's solution was over-engineered, I thought may be he was using different queries..

Comment: This answer was correct. Many times users forget to accept the answer, its good to mention.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    c.Zip, c.State,COUNT (DISTINCT c.CustomerNumber)
FROM 
    Customer c
        INNER JOIN TransactionDetail t
            ON 
                c.CustomerNumber = t.CustomerNumber AND
                c.ProductXPref = 1 --Indicates if Customer was part of ProductX promotion program.
                AND t.TransactionDate > DATEADD(DD, -60, getdate()) 
WHERE t.ProductXIndicator <> 1 

GROUP BY c.Zip, c.State
```

Answer (score 0):

after some validation the numbers did not match what I expect those to be, hence I have tried different logic which worked fine and returned what I wanted. So posting the answer here, again thanks for all the help.

```
SELECT d.State, d.Zip, COUNT(DISTINCT(d.CustomerNumber)) AS 'Active Customers'
    INTO #ProductDifference
    FROM Customer c
    INNER JOIN 
    TransactionDetail t
    ON 
    c.CustomerNumber = t.CustomerNumber
    WHERE d.ProductXPref = 1
    AND t.TransactionDate > DATEADD(d, -60, getdate())
AND c.CustomerNumber
NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT d.[CustomerNumber] 
FROM Customer d 
     INNER JOIN
    TransactionDetail f
     ON 
     d.CustomerNumber = f.CustomerNumber
WHERE f.ProductXIndicator = 1
    AND f.TransactionDate > DATEADD(DD, -60, getdate()) 
    AND d.ProductXPref = 1)
GROUP BY c.State, c.Zip
```